# syntax to create dictionary in particular order using python?

Tags: python

```
data={isbn1:[{
              name:
              desc:
              price:[producturl:_]
              review:[website1:[R1,R2,R3],website2[]]
              }]
     isbn2:[{



           }]

}
```

I am new to python so I don't know to print this dict in this order.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: Give a try with ordereddict